# RecyclerView with GoogleMap in one element. Map not refreshing

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview, android-mapview, android-viewholder

In an app. The first view in a recyclerView contains a map (similar to the google traffic recommendations in google now). All other Views represent the same sort of data, but without the map. When I update the data in onBindViewHolder all the data get's updated except for the map which stays as it was. When I close the app and open it the correct map is loaded.
I tried to clear the map with `.clear()`, I also tried to invalidate the MapView, but nothing seems to help. I marked the code which I think must contain the error, but to be sure I posted the entire ViewHolder. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

```
public static class PingsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback{
    public ImageView mFirstLetter;
    public TextView mNamesOrPhoneNumbers;
    public MapView mPingMapView;
    public GoogleMap mPingGoogleMap;
    public TextView mPingDate;
    public Button mPingButton;
    private List<Location> mPingLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    private Bundle savedInstanceState;

    private Observable<List<Location>> locationsObserver() {
        return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(mPingLocations));
    }

    iItemViewHolderClicks mListener;

    public PingsViewHolder(View root, int viewType) {
        super(root);
        switch (viewType) {
            case PING_WITH_MAP_VIEW_TYPE:
                mFirstLetter = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.first_letter_image_view_ping);
                mNamesOrPhoneNumbers = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.ping_names_text_view);
                mPingDate = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.ping_last_date_text_view);
                mPingMapView = (MapView) root.findViewById(R.id.ping_map_view);
                mPingMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mPingMapView.getMapAsync(this);
                mPingButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.ping_element_button);
                locationsObserver().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).map(locations -> {
//------------------Start of suspicious code -------------------
                    mPingGoogleMap.clear();
                    LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                    for (Location location : locations) {
                        Double lat = location.getLatitude();
                        Double lng = location.getLongitude();
                        boundsBuilder.include(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                        mPingGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(lat, lng)));
                    }
                    LatLngBounds bounds = boundsBuilder.build();
                    mPingGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));
//------------------End of suspicious code --------------------------
                    return true;
                }).retryWhen((foo) -> Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).subscribe();
                root.setOnClickListener(this);
                break;
            case PING_VIEW_TYPE:
                mFirstLetter = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.first_letter_image_view_ping);
                mNamesOrPhoneNumbers = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.ping_names_text_view);
                mPingDate = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.ping_last_date_text_view);
                mPingButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.ping_element_button);
                root.setOnClickListener(this);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mPingGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mPingGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    }

    public void appendMarker(Location location){
        mPingLocations.add(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getLayoutPosition();
        if (mSelected.contains(position)) {
            mSelected.remove(position);
        } else {
            mSelected.add(getLayoutPosition());
        }
        if (getItemViewType() == PING_WITH_MAP_VIEW_TYPE){
            mPingMapView.invalidate();
        }
        mListener.onItemClick(v);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(iItemViewHolderClicks listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface iItemViewHolderClicks {
        void onItemClick(View caller);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the full blown MapView, or will a litemode (bitmap only) work?

Comment: @chessdork I think it woud work as long as I can put markers on it.

Comment: @chessdork Turns out I was already using the litemode. So this is not the problem.

Comment: Deletion of markers must be done by using `.clear()` just one call to this method should be enough to remove all the markers on your map. Then, add markers using `.addMarker()`. Check this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#public-methods

Comment: @d.datul1990 But isn't this what i already do?